# Enable SharePoint VisualWebPart (wsp) to SubSite

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm working on SharePoint 2010 I've created my visual webpart and deployed as farm soultion on Site Collection, now this webpart is not visible in my subsite

http://ServerName:50000/ here wsp file is available

http://ServerName:50000/sites/Subsite here wsp is not available

Things which I tried are as following

Site Settings of your top level site
Under Site Collection Administration, click Site Collection Features
Click on Activate for Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure
Once that’s activated, please go back to site settings page
Under site administration, click on site features
Activate Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

You can't deploy a farm solution to a particular site collection. Either you can deploy it Globally or for a single web application. Apart from this, As Per your information its look like,

http://ServerName:50000/ &

http://ServerName:50000/sites/Subsite are two different site collections.

So, You have to deploy your wsp to web application level, so it will be available in all your site collections & subsites. (After deploying solution make sure your solution feature is activated in site collection features)

Comment: This is one WebApplication and it have subsite and after deployment solution is available at WebApplication level, but not at subsite level

Comment: Are u checked that your feature is activated at http://ServerName:50000/sites/Subsite ?

Comment: I've activated my feature from  "Site Collection Features" however it not available in the list of Manage site features of my main web application

Comment: Webparts resides at site collection level. So feature is also at available in site collection features not at site feature. Activating feature at site collection level will add your webpart to site. Please verify that now webpart is available in site or not.